# unable to sen ID from View to Controller at Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I tried many things to send ID from view to controller but failed at Spring MVC. I am not able to get the ID as I receive only ID for myID. Could you please help me to fix it ? I think I catch a small thing.

View :

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="/showthebutton/{myId}(myId ='123')}" th:action="@{/showthebutton}"  th:object="${model}" method="post">
 <button type="submit"
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-primary">
    <th:block th:text="#{label.customerdetails.button.limits}">
        Show Button
    </th:block>
</button>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/showthebutton/{myId}")
public String showlimit(@PathVariable(value = "myId") Long myId,@ModelAttribute Model model) {
ResponseEntity<List<DTO>> entityLisy = myEndpoint.getDTO(myId);
```

Comment: Why did you post that part of the view? What does it have to do with sending an ID? Why not post the code that you tried and that is supposed to send the ID?

Comment: i have to send the ID and get it from the controller. but iID comes null

Comment: The value of th:action is `@{/showthebutton}`. I don't know thymeleaf very well, but I don't see why that would append an ID to the path.

Comment: that should not make different NizetI think. Even when I remove th:Action i can't get the ID from controller as well